# How to make result from one odoo field to affect the result of another field

Tags: odoo-10

I have  a time difference field

```
time_diff = fields.Char(string="Time Difference", required=False, )
```

and a sla field in odoo

```
sla_state = fields.Selection(string="SLA", selection=[('past sla', 'Past SLA'), ('within sla', 'Within SLA'), ], required=False, )
```

i want to set a condition where if time difference is greater than 1
the sla state automatically populates to Past SLA
Below is my function

```
@api.onchange('time_diff')
    def get_sla(self):
        if self.time_diff >= 1:
            self.sla_state == 'past sla'
        else:
            self.sla_state == 'within sla'
```

But its not working what might be the issue
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are comparing the string with integer. Data type of 'time_diff' is string. So string can not be compared with integer. Convert the string to integer using *int()*

```
@api.onchange('time_diff')
def get_sla(self):
    if self.time_dif:
        if int(self.time_diff) >= 1:
           self.sla_state == 'past sla'
        else:
           self.sla_state == 'within sla'
```